# problem to product a specific plot on python

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have some difficulties to product a graphic.
I have lot of data but to simplify my issue I will reduce the number of data.

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[0.5, 1, "mediaset"],
        [0.4, 1.2, "cnn"],
        [0.8, 1.7, "abcnews"], 
        [0.9, 1.4, "cnn"],
        [0.4, 1.2, "mediaset"], 
        [0.75, 1.67, "cnn"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['cpc','rate_bid','site'],dtype=float)
```

I would like to have a plot with  : x = cpc, y = rate_bid and 3 curves (mediaset, abcnews, cnn)

How could I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='cpc', y='rate_bid', hue='site')
```

Output:

[image]